# same library in different packages doesn't work

Tags: android, gradle, build

After updating to the latest gradle, I get a weird error when building the project:

```
[:feature_x, :feature_y] all package the same library  [com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart].
```

I have indeed added this library in both features. They are set as a dependency like:

```
api "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:$rootProject.MPAndroidChart"
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Just a quick question... is the error message something more like `:feature_x, feature_y`? I'm having a similar issue and wanted to make sure we have an accurate description

Comment: Sorry for late reply. but you are right.
i have reported a bug on buganizer. For now they seem to not want to fix it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116852261

Comment: you might want to use AGP 4.0 (but still preview) https://medium.com/@jamieadkins95/a-quick-look-at-feature-on-feature-dependencies-in-android-gradle-plugin-4-0-0-5828915d02d3

Answer (score 8):

As of 2018-10, this is expected behavior, according to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116852261) in Google's issue tracker:

> Yes, multiple non-base features depending on the same library is currently not supported because both of the features will package the library, but there's no guarantee that they'll package the same *version* of the library, which can lead to crashes at runtime. We opted to fail the build in these cases to prevent unexpected behavior at runtime.
>
> Unfortunately, adding the library as a dependency to the base module is the suggested workaround for this.

Comment: This tip is fine, thanks!!!
In my case I have a 'core' module that depends on a 'commons' (views/ui) and all my features (Feat_x, Feat_y, Feat_z) depends on 'core' module, it means that all features can use all the sub-modules in 'commons'. 
Suggested architecture:
https://github.com/vmadalin/android-modular-architecture/blob/master/screenshots/architecture/diagram_communication_modules.png
Solved